# JSON parsing odd node

Tags: ios, json

I am parsing something like this from this website: http://www.prindlepost.org/?json=1

```
posts: [
{
....
categories: [],
tags: [],
....
```

One of the tags within 'post' is this:

```
author: {
id: 43,
slug: "connergordon_2016",
name: "Conner Gordon",
first_name: "Conner",
last_name: "Gordon",
nickname: "connergordon_2016",
url: "",
description: "Conner is a web and social media intern at the Prindle Institute. A Political Science major from Indiana, Conner's ethical interests lie in memory studies, conflict analysis and the ethics of representation. He also has interests in literature, art and photography."
},
```

This is how I am parsing the rest successfully:

```
// convert to JSON
NSError *myError = nil;
NSDictionary *res = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&myError];

// extract specific value...
NSArray *results = [res objectForKey:@"posts"];

for (NSDictionary *result in results)
{
   ....
   // loop through the array of categories
    NSArray *categories = [result objectForKey:@"categories"];

    for (NSDictionary *category in categories)
    {
        // ID
        NSString *tempIDCategoryString = [category objectForKey:@"id"];
        NSInteger *UniqueCategoryID = [tempIDCategoryString intValue];

        // slug
        NSString *Categoryslug = [category objectForKey:@"slug"];

        // title
        NSString *Categorytitle = [category objectForKey:@"title"];

        // description
        NSString *Categorydescription = [category objectForKey:@"description"];

        // parent
        NSString *Categoryparent = [category objectForKey:@"parent"];

        // post_count
        NSString *Categorypost_count = [category objectForKey:@"post_count"];
    }
    // </categories>
}
```

I have no idea how to parse this author node out of the array of objects within 'post'. Its not an array and it doesn't look like a JSON object to me. I might be wrong though. Help?

Comment: try `[results[@"author"] valueForKey:@"id"];` outside loop

Comment: Yes! that was it. thanks so much! if you answer this question, I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its very much simple...just access it with `valueForKey`

```
 NSArray *results = [res objectForKey:@"posts"];
[results[@"author"] valueForKey:@"id"];
```

And you are done

Answer (score 1):

Author is a dictionary node.You can try this.

```
 for (NSDictionary *result in results)
{
   ....
   //get the author dictionary
    NSDictionary *postDict = [result objectForKey:@"author"];
   // loop through the array of categories
    NSArray *categories = [result objectForKey:@"categories"];
   ...
 }
```